# Dirac Delta-Like Integrations in Quantum Field Theory

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions

I am working on exercises in *Introduction to Quantum Field Theory* by Peskin and Schroeder and throughout many of my derivations I often encountered integrals like this: $$\int d^3p d^3p' \delta^3(p - p')e^{i(p\cdot x + p'\cdot y)}.$$ Here the $p $s in the dirac delta are three-vectors and the $p,x,y$s in the exponent are four vectors. Here is how I tried to evaluate this:

$$\int d^3p d^3p' \delta^3(p - p')e^{i(p\cdot x + p'\cdot y)} = \int d^3p d^3p' \delta^3(p - p')e^{i(E_p\cdot t_x + E_{p'}\cdot t_y)}e^{^{-i(p \cdot x + p'\cdot y)}}.$$ Now the $p,x,y$s in the exponent are three vectors. Thus:

$$\int d^3p d^3p' \delta^3(p - p')e^{i(E_p(t_x - t_y))}e^{^{-ip\cdot(x + y)}} = \int d^3p d^3p' \delta^3(p - p')e^{i(E_p\Delta t)}e^{^{-ip\cdot(x + y)}} = \int d^3pe^{i(E_p\Delta t)}e^{^{-ip\cdot(x + y)}} = \int d^3p e^{ip\cdot (x - y)}.$$

Note that in the very last integral expression the $p,x,y$s in the exponent are four vectors. If I let $\Delta t = 0$ then the integral is the three dimensional dirac delta function $(2\pi)^3\delta^3(x - y)$, where $x,y$ are position three vectors.

**Now, if I do not let** $\Delta t = 0$, **then is the integral of four vectors** $\int d^3p e^{ip\cdot (x - y)}$ **the four dimensional dirac delta function** $(2\pi)^4\delta^4(x - y)$ **where x and y are four vectors? If not, what is this integral?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purely formally, I think your expression should evaluate as
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int d^3p\int d^3q\,\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{q})\,e^{ipx+iqy}=\int d^3p\,e^{ipx+iq_0y_0}\int d^3q\,\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{q})\,e^{-i\mathbf{q}\mathbf{y}}\\
&&=\int d^3p\,e^{ipx+iq_0y_0}\,e^{-i\mathbf{p}\mathbf{y}}=
e^{ip_0x_0+iq_0y_0}\int d^3p\,e^{-i\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y})}\\
&&=(2\pi)^3e^{ip_0x_0+iq_0y_0}\,\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y})\,.
\end{eqnarray}
In Peskin & Schroeder I did however not see an integral like this. On p.27 they study causality and consider the propagator
$$
D(x-y)=
\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2E_\mathbf{p}}e^{-ip(x-y)}\,.
$$
For that they get quite different expressions depending on $x_0>y_0$ or $x_0=y_0\,.$

Answer (score 0):

If the three vectors obey ${\bf p}= {\bf p'}$ then $E_{\bf p}=E_{{\bf p}'}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made that observation in the following lines in my post: $\int d^3p d^3p' \delta^3(p - p')e^{i(E_p(t_x - t_y))}e^{^{-ip\cdot(x + y)}} = \int d^3p d^3p' \delta^3(p - p')e^{i(E_p\Delta t)}e^{^{-ip\cdot(x + y)}} = \int d^3pe^{i(E_p\Delta t)}e^{^{-ip\cdot(x + y)}} = \int d^3p e^{ip\cdot (x - y)}$. My question is how do I evaluate the final integral?

Comment: As I said:  It is $ (2\pi)^3\delta^3(p-p')$.

Comment: I am confused; shouldn't time be included, like $E_p t_x - E_{p'}t_y$?

Comment: Can you give an example of the integrals from P&S? If the $t$ is the not the same it does not make sense.

Comment: Why does t have to be the same? For instance, I am computing the commutation relations in problem 2.2 (a). The way I interpreted the four vectors $x,y$ is as follows: each represents a 4-event in the same reference frame. Each four-event can have a unique location of occurrence, given by the three vectors x and y and a time of occurrence, which I denoted as $t_x$ and $t_y$. To me it seems possible for $t_x \neq t_y$. Is my interpretation incorrect with respect to the exercise 2.2 (a)? If so, in what way?